# Identifer Expected when using HashMap with Character

Tags: java, hashmap, character

I am trying to store values as Characters, Integers in HashMap, but keep getting error Identifier Expected.

This is the code that i am writing :

```
HashMap<Character,Integer> romanMp = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
Character c = new Character('I');
romanMp.put(c, 1);
```

Could anyone help in that.
Thanks very much.
Ibrahim.

Comment: Can you post the actual error and not the description of the error?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, this code runs as expected, please post the full code.  After some research it seems you are not putting this into a method?  Put it inside of `public static void main(String [] args) { }`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, I got the idea from your comments. I moved it inside as :  HashMap<Character, Integer> romanMp = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();


    public int romanToInt(String s) {

        romanMp.put(new Character('I'),1);